# Want to create multiple objects of a class at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a complete fresher I have been told to create a class for Candidate ..
after creating the database for the module. What I have created is

```
public class Class1
{
   public class JobHistory
    {
     public string CompName, Tech, Profile;
     public string StartDate;
     public string EndtDate;
     public int CurrentAnnualSalary;
     public void AddNew(string CompName, string Tech, string Profile, 
                           string StartDate, string EndtDate, 
                           int CurrentAnnualSalary)
        {
            this.CompName = CompName;
            this.Tech = Tech;
            this.Profile = Profile;
            this.StartDate = StartDate;
            this.EndtDate = EndtDate;
            this.CurrentAnnualSalary = CurrentAnnualSalary;

        }
    }
    public class PersonalInformation
    {
        public string FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, PhoneNo1, PhoneNo2;
        public string EmailId;
        public int TotalExperienceInMonths;

        public void AddNew(string FirstName, string LastName, string DateOfBirth,
                           string PhoneNo1, string PhoneNo2, 
                           int TotalExperienceInMonths, string EmailId)
        {
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.LastName = LastName;
            this.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
            this.PhoneNo1 = PhoneNo1;
            this.PhoneNo2 = PhoneNo2;
            this.EmailId = EmailId;
            this.TotalExperienceInMonths = TotalExperienceInMonths;

        }
    }

    public class Skills
    {
         int SkillId;
         string Skill;
    }
    public class Candidate
    {
        int CandidateId;
        JobHistory jh1 = new JobHistory();
        PersonalInformation pi = new PersonalInformation();

        public void AddNew(int CandidateId,JobHistory jh2,PersonalInformation pi2)
        {
            this.CandidateId = CandidateId;
            this.jh1.AddNew(jh2.CompName, jh2.Tech, jh2.Profile, 
                            jh2.StartDate, jh2.EndtDate, 
                            jh2.CurrentAnnualSalary);

            this.pi.AddNew(pi2.FirstName, pi2.LastName, pi2.DateOfBirth,
                           pi2.PhoneNo1, pi2.PhoneNo2, 
                           pi2.TotalExperienceInMonths, pi2.EmailId);
        }
        public void UpdateExisting();
        public void Delete();

    }
}
```

here I wanted to another class of Skills.
But from the frond end the candidate will have multiple skills and he will update them. So for that I wanted the objects of class skills to be created at the runtime so should I be using the `List<>`? How to go ahead? Am I correct till now?

Comment: Aside from anything else, your `AddNew` methods don't do what they say they do - they just set a bunch of fields. It would be better to make your *constructors* do that. (And don't use public fields - use properties backed by private fields, possibly via automatically implemented properties.) But yes, `List<T>` is a nice simple collection to use in many cases... have you *tried* using that? What happened? It's not clear where you're actually stuck.

Comment: I'd also recommend ditching `Class1` - make all of these top-level classes. Nested classes are rarely required.

Comment: first thanks for your reply..what i wanted was how should i write the codes to create the list<> items at runtime

Comment: Well what have you *tried* along those lines? You create an instance of `List<T>`, and repeatedly create instance of the class you want, adding the reference into the list with the `Add` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon skeet mentioned you need to use the `Constructor` and you need to remove the `class1` nested class rarely required.

Start with writing constructor for your classes in place of `AddNew` method like below

```
public class JobHistory
{
 public string CompName, Tech, Profile;
 public string StartDate;
 public string EndtDate;
 public int CurrentAnnualSalary;
 public JobHistory(string CompName, string Tech, string Profile, 
                       string StartDate, string EndtDate, 
                       int CurrentAnnualSalary)
    {
        this.CompName = CompName;
        this.Tech = Tech;
        this.Profile = Profile;
        this.StartDate = StartDate;
        this.EndtDate = EndtDate;
        this.CurrentAnnualSalary = CurrentAnnualSalary;

    }

 //If required then you can also need write out the empty constructor 
    public JobHistory(){}     

}
```

You can also change your `class1` into the namespace so your classes can stay in same `namespace`. [More info on namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx)

```
 namespace StudeProfileProject
```

And one more thing, If you are declaring the properties as public then use the `getters` and `setters` at the time of declaration so your final class will be look like,

```
public class JobHistory
{
 public string CompName{get;set}
 public string Tech {get;set;}
 public string Profile{get;set;}

 //More properties ....
 public JobHistory()
 {}


 public JobHistory(string CompName, string Tech, string Profile, 
                       string StartDate, string EndtDate, 
                       int CurrentAnnualSalary)
    {
        this.CompName = CompName;
        this.Tech = Tech;
        this.Profile = Profile;
        this.StartDate = StartDate;
        this.EndtDate = EndtDate;
        this.CurrentAnnualSalary = CurrentAnnualSalary;

    }

}
```

If you want multiple skills for each `Candidate` then `List` will be good option and you can declare it in the your Candidate class

```
  public class Candidate
  {
    int CandidateId;
    JobHistory jh1 = new JobHistory();
    PersonalInformation pi = new PersonalInformation();

    List<Skill> CandidateSkills = new List<Skills>();        

    public Candidate(int CandidateId,JobHistory jh2,PersonalInformation pi2)
    {
        this.CandidateId = CandidateId;
        this.jh1= new JobHistory (jh2.CompName, jh2.Tech, jh2.Profile, 
                        jh2.StartDate, jh2.EndtDate, 
                        jh2.CurrentAnnualSalary);

        this.pi =  new PersonalInformation (pi2.FirstName, pi2.LastName, pi2.DateOfBirth,
                       pi2.PhoneNo1, pi2.PhoneNo2, 
                       pi2.TotalExperienceInMonths, pi2.EmailId);
    }
    public void UpdateExisting();
    public void Delete();

}
```

And you will be able to use all the `Collection` methods for your need. [Here is more info on it.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, you could replace the AddNew-Methods with Constructors.

For your Candidate class it could look like this:
    `public Candidate(int CandidateId,JobHistory jh2,PersonalInformation pi2)`

Using a `List<Skill>` is a good idea. You can then use the `Add`-Method to add a skill.